# Question related to first order partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, derivatives

If The funtion $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ has directional derivatives in all directions at each point in $\Bbb R^2$ then the function $f$ has first order partail derivatives at each point in $\Bbb R^2$

How can I prove this? Please do not downvote because of not saying any idea or my tried. I cannot produce any idea to prove this. Please help me thank you

Comment: The directions $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ give the partial derivatives

Comment: How? Please  Explain more.. @Bunder

Comment: It just is :) . Think a little, do some sketches.

Comment: Well, thank you:) @Bunder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** Use the definitions.

What does it mean for $f$ to have directional derivatives in all direction at each point in $\Bbb R^2$?

It means that for all vectors $(k,l)\in \Bbb R^2$ and for all points $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$ the following limit exists: 
$$\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f((x,y)+h(k,l))-f(x,y)}{h}\right) \tag 1$$

Now set $(k,l)=(1,0)$ and $(k,l)=(0,1)$ in $(1)$ and  check the definition of partial derivative.

**Partial answer** (pun)**:**

$\begin{align} \displaystyle \lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f((x,y)+h(1,0))-f(x,y)}{h}\right)&=\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \end{align}$

The last equality only holds because the first limit exists and because it is equal to the second limit in the chain of equalities above.

Comment: Okay I know the equation (1) is the definiton of directional derivatives. For ($k,l)=(1,0)$ $lim (\frac{f(x,y)+h(1,0)-f(x,y))}{h})$ as $h \to 0$ Then, $lim\frac {f(x+1.p,0)-f(x,y)}{h}$ the limit exists and similar to $(k,l)=(0,1)$ So f has partial derivatives

Comment: Is all I did right?

Comment: Also definition of partial derivative is $lim \frac{f(x+te_i)-f(x)}{t}$ as $t\to 0$

Comment: @B11b No. First off there are parentheses missing. It should be $f((x,y)+h(1,0))$. Then how do you go from $f((x,y)+h(1,0))$ to $f((x+1.p,0)$? I don't even understand the notation.

Comment: Well, I saw such a transition like this from an example. I tried to apply that to here. Sorry for the mistake:( how can I do? :(

Comment: @B11b I added a partial derivative to the answer.

Comment: Okay, got it! I understand how to rewrite this. I am studying by myself on holiday for next semester. Thus, sometimes I am mislearning, and I am asking too many questions here. Thank you!@GitGud :)

Comment: @B11b Good luck. No problem.